# bash scripting removing optional <Integer><colon> prefix

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a list with all of the content is like:

```
1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-28.git20131003.fc20.x86_64  
avahi-0.6.31-21.fc20.x86_64     
2:irqbalance-1.0.7-1.fc20.x86_64   
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.12-2.fc20.x86_64     
mdadm-3.3-4.fc20.x86_64
```

I need to remove the N: but leave the rest of strings as is.
Have tried:

```
cat service-rpmu.list | sed -ne "s/#[#:]\+://p" > end.list  
cat service-rpmu.list | egrep -o '#[#:]+' > end.list
```

both result in an empty end.list

```
//* the N:, just denotes an epoch version */
```

Comment: what is `N`? what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\+://' your.file
```

Output:

```
NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-28.git20131003.fc20.x86_64  
avahi-0.6.31-21.fc20.x86_64     
irqbalance-1.0.7-1.fc20.x86_64   
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.12-2.fc20.x86_64     
mdadm-3.3-4.fc20.x86_64
```

Btw, your list looks like the output of a grep command with the option `-n`. If this is true, then omit the `-n` option there. Also it is likely that your whole task can be done with a single `sed` command.

Comment: Is part of a longer thing:

Comment: Is part of a longer thing:  `find /usr/lib/systemd /etc/systemd -name '*.service' -printf '*/%f\n' > find.list  \ && yum whatprovides $(cat find.list) | sed -n -e '/x86_64/{p;n;}' > service-rpm.list  \   && cat service-rpm.list | egrep -o '^[^ ]+' > service-rpmu.list` "I haven't figured out to get everything piped toghether as yet, checking it bit by bit"

Comment: currently just having ubuntu. can test on a fedora later

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '{ sub(/^.*:/,""); print}' sample
```

Comment: Thank you for deactivating the syntax highlighting in the output section of my answer. nice tweak :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{print $NF}’ service-rpmu.list
```